# How to add username in the url dynimically in Codeigniter php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

When we can login to the admin site, that particular user's name will be shown in the URL before the controller.

Comment: Is the form's `method` `POST`.. once check it..

Comment: You should paste some code of what you have tried or you are most likely to get down voted. I have not down voted you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly worded and ambiguous. It's probably a good idea to rewrite it to make it more clear.

What I feel that you're asking, is that you **want** to display a user's name after the domain, but before the controller; e.g. `http://www.example.com/username/controller/method/parameter`?

If this is the case, you can do this with a custom route like:
`$route['(:any)/controller/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/$2/$3';`

If you'd like the username to be passed as a parameter as well:
`$route['(:any)/controller/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/$2/$1/$3';`

Obviously depending on the desired function of your application, you could choose to replace the `(:any)` parts of the route as necessary.

As for actually adding the username to the URL itself, that will be based on your application when it's building the links inside your admin section.